# A list of all functions from X to Y in Python

Tags: python

I have two finite sets X and Y, and I want to generate a list containing all of the functions from X to Y (that is, all mappings from X to Y, where each mapping is represented as a dictionary whose keys are elements of X, and whose values are elements of Y; note that a mapping from X to Y must have a key for every element of X). For example, if X = {1,2} and Y = {'a','b'}, I want to obtain the following list of dictionaries.

```
[{1:'a',2:'a'},{1:'a',2:'b'},{1:'b',2:'a'},{1:'b',2:'b'}]
```

I think the following code satisfies my needs, but I am trying to get better at being Pythonic, so I was wondering if there is a one-liner that does not need the recursive helper function.

```
def ntuples(A,n):
    if n == 0:
        return {()}
    else:
        return {x + (a,) for x in ntuples(A,n-1) for a in A}
def X_to_Y(X,Y):
    return [{x:y[i] for (i,x) in enumerate(X)} for y in ntuples(Y,len(X))]
```

Comment: I think some people may not know what you mean by "all functions".  I think you should say all possible mappings from A into B.

Comment: I updated the question to incorporate your suggestion. I am unconvinced that this question merited a hold for being unclear, though. I understand that my use of the term "function" is more appropriate for a math forum than a programming forum. However, the original question included a concrete example, and code that (somewhat inefficiently) solves the problem. Additionally, there was a correct answer within five minutes of the question being posted, so the meaning was evidently conveyed to at least one person with no confusion.

Comment: I did not vote to close your question.  I didn't think it was unclear at all, I was just guessing at what the person who voted to close it wasn't understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chasing one-liners is the *opposite* of pythonic, but avoiding recursion is often a good idea. In this case, we can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to take care of the hard part, and then wrap that in a listcomp:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> X = {1,2}
>>> Y = {'a','b'}
>>> [dict(zip(X,y)) for y in product(Y,repeat=len(X))]
[{1: 'a', 2: 'a'}, {1: 'b', 2: 'a'}, {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, {1: 'b', 2: 'b'}]
```

(I'm assuming you don't care too much about whether you see `{1: 'b', 2: 'a'}` or `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}` first in the list.)

And remember that if there's no need to materialize the list at all once, you could replace `[` and `]` with `(` and `)` to use a generator expression instead of a listcomp, which you could iterate over.